# Limit textarea symbols to visible part

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to limit textarea entered symbols to visible part only?

I don't want scrolling, I have specified number of rows column for it and I want that user could not enter so many characters that possible scrolling will appear.

Of course I could set overflow:hidden but symbols anyway will be entered. Limiting to the number of characters is not my case, because different character take different width: for example W and 1. I need this logic because data entered in textarea are used on some print report and there is no possibility for scrolling in paper.

I have found only 2 possible solutions:

1. Use some average number of
   characters. And limit by this
   number. This is very rough. Because
   for strings with average number of
   big characters greater than usual it
   will still hide some data.
2. Use rendering of entered
   characters to some separate div and
   calculate its width/height. Seem to
   me will be very slow and not
   sure this is the correct implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JavaScript to check the `scrollHeight` and if bigger than the "original" height, truncate the text until it has no scroll anymore. Code for this would be:

```
function CheckScroll(oTextarea) {
    if (oTextarea.scrollHeight > oTextarea.offsetHeight) {
        while (oTextarea.scrollHeight > oTextarea.offsetHeight) {
            oTextarea.value = oTextarea.value.substr(0, oTextarea.value.length - 1);
         }
    }
}
```

And to trigger it:

```
<textarea cols="15" rows="3" onkeyup="CheckScroll(this);" onchange="CheckScroll(this);" onpaste="CheckScroll(this);"></textarea>
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/bNqVf/1/

Comment: `onkeyup` is a poor approach for this sort of thing.  It makes it all very clunky (try keeping your finger on the key, for instance).  Also, in Chrome 9 too many characters are removed.

Comment: when I entered big enough text it truncates not last symbol but half of the last string (ff 3.6).

Comment: @Yau Don't have any better idea ATM.. sorry. Other idea I had but is worse IMO is having separate textboxes one below the other e.g. three textboxes then using JS to imitate word wrap.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with something similar to Shadow Wizard's effort which uses `oninput` to detect all forms of input (like pasting, drag/drop), not just keyboard input.  It requires switching off the scrollbars of the textarea with the following CSS:

```
textarea { overflow: hidden; }
```

You might want to set `resize: none;` for browsers like Firefox 4 and Chrome.  Also, Opera's wrapping doesn't break if there are no spaces, but it doesn't support `word-wrap: word-break;` properly so I'm not sure how you'd work around this.  The JavaScript involves remembering the content of the textarea each time it changes and, if the text exceeds the size of the element, the change is reverted to the previous value:

```
var prev = "",
    tArea = document.getElementById("limit");

// Need to use onpropertychange event for IE8 and lower
if ("onpropertychange" in tArea && !("oninput" in tArea)) {
    tArea.onpropertychange = function () {
        // Only run code if value property changes
        if (window.event.propertyName == "value")
            this.oninput();
    }
}

// oninput will fire for all types of input, not just keyboard
tArea.oninput = function () {
    // Temporarily remove the onpropertychange event to prevent a stack overflow
    var opc = this.onpropertychange;
    this.onpropertychange = null;

    // Revert value if the text exceeds the size of the box
    if (this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight) {
        this.value = prev;
    }

    prev = this.value;

    if (opc)
        this.onpropertychange = opc;
}
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/37Jnn/** - tested in Firefox 4, IE8, Chrome 9, Opera 10.

Comment: Also not work as expected value is still not truncated. see screenshot in firebug : http://i.imgur.com/f1S9N.jpg

Comment: @Yauhen: then I think you'll struggle to achieve this in a fully cross browser manner.

Answer (score 1):

You could style it to use Courier, or some other non-proportional font. That way, you'd know exactly how many characters could fit, since all characters are the same size, which would make it easy to limit it using any one of several well-known techniques for limiting the number of characters in the string.

The downside is that it wouldn't look pretty (unless you happen to like how Courier looks), but it is a workable solution, and I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score -1):

Just to summarize. I will exclude Courier font solution from discussion. Because in most cases it is not acceptable. Both solutions that use key up/property changes has drawback:
visually text is entered and only then removed.

Making substr(0, oTextarea.value.length - 1) has problems when last symbol is \n in IE. In this case it will hang because \r symbol is left. So it should be used oTextarea.value.length - 2 in case of last \n.

For on property change should be used some multi browser solution. For example like [this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/478985.aspx)

The only possible way to make such checks user friendly (not allowing entering) is to create for each text area other hidden text area and make all checks on this text area in events before data are really shown in original text area (like key down). But in this case it will require handling of all selection ranges, pastes and reapplying them on hidden. And logic will be not trivial.